# codeigniter live domain setup issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation, live

On local CI setup is working fine but when I uploaded on server it shows this error:

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

I have tried some of the changes like change the system folder path but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check your permission. The web server user may not have permissions to read everything.

Comment: What was it before and how did you change it? Edit your question and put that code  in here. Sidenote: [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Read it because it can help you in the future.

Comment: thanks Saty it was helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading all the files to server, first install ci on server, Check if you are able to view welcome page. Once you can see welcome page, upload other files